How can I access the request user in a Django REST Framework serializer?
I'm currently working on a Django project and using Djoser for user authentication. where I need to access the request user within a serializer.

class TokenRefreshSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    refresh = serializers.CharField()
    access = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    token_class = RefreshToken
    
    def validate(self, attrs: Dict[str, Any]) -> Dict[str, str]:
        refresh = self.token_class(attrs["refresh"])
        
        data = {"access": str(refresh.access_token)}

        if api_settings.ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS:
            if api_settings.BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION:
                try:
                    # Attempt to blacklist the given refresh token
                    refresh.blacklist()
                except AttributeError:
                    # If blacklist app not installed, `blacklist` method will
                    # not be present
                    pass

            refresh.set_jti()
            refresh.set_exp()
            refresh.set_iat()

            # 1 option
            user_id = refresh['user_id']
            user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

        return data

How can I access the request user here?
user = self.context['request'].user
            
print( user)

But i have AnonymousUser

The ViewSet using the serializer should have get_serializer_context method which can be used to provide the serializer with additional data
class MyViewSet(GenericViewSet):
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(MyViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
        context.update({
            "request_user": self.request.user # or whatever field contains the current user
        })
        return context

Technically, you can put whatever you wish in the context (even the whole request) and pass it down to serializer, but I would advise you to use this carefully as it may overcomplicate things
